# Regarding GPU and drawcalls redirecting

Tags: opengl, directx, rpc

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with redirecting drawcalls in OpenGL and/or DirectX, possibly with drivers.

I am looking into redirecting the drawcalls from the cloud to clients with my hunch that it would be lighter in the long term than streaming video. The main problem would be the transfer of textures as I see it currently.

Is this the case? What is the bandwidth requirement roughly of the sending (and receiving of ack's and errors) of drawcalls? I wouldn't think it would be exactly much (as with most RPC calls), but am I missing something here?

Is there a real need for a physical GPU on the server end?

Would there be a distinct difference between DirectX and OpenGL redirecting?

Are there any other limitations I need to worry about?

And last but not least, is this been done before? I know it has been done in VirtualBox and other virtual machines; so to some extent it would be feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the (now dead) [chromium](http://chromium.sourceforge.net/) project which was the basis for the GL stuff used in VirtualBox. Using this to just redirect the GL stream over network is just a small part of its features. It allowed the manipulation of the GL command stream and focused on distributed rendering. However, with the advent of shaders, that way of stream manipulation is not working very well any more, so the project got pretty much stuck at GL1.x...

You should also be aware that the glX protocol is network transparent by design and forwarding GL command streams works out of the box on X11, you'll just lose the "direct rendering" ability.

Comment: Note that with modern OpenGL, i.e. everything done using Buffer Objects, *direct rendering* is rendered obsolete. Unfortunately there's no GLX transport support for modern OpenGL yet. It's time, somebody just implements a GLX4, that directly supports modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualGL ( http://www.virtualgl.org/ ) might be something you might want to look at, especially since it's open source. It works the opposite way (the GPU is on the server), but the principles should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

These are some papers that are worth reading on the subject:

http://wand.net.nz/sites/default/files/clustergl-egpgviz-2011.pdf

http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2005/Papers_2005/Journal/G67-full.pdf